# How to use your own documentation for functions override with apple's quickdoc in xcode?

Tags: xcode, markdown, code-documentation

Is it possible to replace Apple's quickdoc for say:

```
viewDidLoad
```

[image: viewDidLoad quickdoc]

By your own eg:

```
/// Sets up our tableview .....
```

And if yes - how ?

I couldn't find any help on xcode's markdown [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html).